# Prometheus Difference jvm_gc_collection_seconds_sum and jvm_gc_pause_seconds

Tags: prometheus, grafana, promql

I found this article where GC Throughput is queried in Prometheus/Grafana as follows:

```
min by(job)(100 - (sum by (job, instance)(increase(jvm_gc_collection_seconds_sum[1m])) * 100 / sum by (job, instance) (increase(process_cpu_seconds_total[1m]))))
```

The author takes the metric besides others `jvm_gc_collection_seconds_sum` to compute GC Throughput. When I look to my Spring Boot Prometheus endpoint I do not find this metric but find instead `jvm_gc_pause_seconds`. It is stated:

```
 #HELP jvm_gc_pause_seconds Time spent in GC pause
```

Is there a difference between this two metrics?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
jvm_gc_collection_seconds_sum
```

is a Prometheus client metric. Now Prometheus client is no more developed for Spring Boot 2.

```
jvm_gc_pause_seconds or jvm_gc_pause_seconds_sum
```

is a Micrometer client metric that is used in Spring Boot.

Comment: But the metrics mean the same?

Comment: yes. names just hardcoded in the frameworks and can differ a bit, for example, jvm_memory_bytes_max for prometheus and jvm_memory_max_bytes for micrometer etc

Comment: We had `gc="G1 Old Generation"` and `gc="G1 Young Generation"` in `jvm_gc_collection_seconds_sum `. But we don't have these in `jvm_gc_pause_seconds_count`. Is there a way to get the GC type?